# Showing question tags inside rss reader

Tags: feature-request, feed, filtering

SE has now so many sites that I switched from browsing directly my favorite sites to subscribing to their rss-feeds. Unfortunately, google reader doesn't show the tags of a question, only question title, text and author name. It would be nice if the tags would be mentioned directly after question title, then the text with author name (and maybe author reputation) and if an answer was already given. If the title and tags are interesting to me, I often read the question text in google reader or open the question url.

I'm aware that I can subscribe via the filter feature to distinct tags, but I browse too much SE sites to set up, maintain, update a system with probably more than 100 tags. A "negative tag" option on https://stackexchange.com/filters to filter, e.g. frequent questions tagged as homework I'm not interested in, would be even better.

Comment: Similar issue here using Opera's "Mail > feeds" facility. This shows the monitored tag name in the feed title, which is fine, but I would like to see the *other tags* for each question, thus providing wider context that's often missing from questions' text. After all - that's the purpose of tags!

Answer (score 1):

You could :

1/ create a list of the feeds you are interested in on the web (google spreadsheet publishing in csv format for example)

2/ create a yahoo pipes :
- fetch the feeds url from your list
- fetch the feeds
- aggegate for each item in title the tags from the category fields that are in the item

a bit complicate, I will wait for simpler answers.